# Azure Data Factory Blob Event triggering multiple times for a single small file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created an ADF blob event based trigger for a pipeline. The file that I am testing with is around 931 kb. When I upload the file, ADF triggers the pipeline three times. Is there some configuration that I am missing here? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Share the configuration of the trigger.

Comment: Also, check `@triggerbody().filename` value in any set variable in the pipeline run to know whether the same file is triggering the pipeline in each run or not.

Comment: Same problem here!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the scenario, but it is working fine for me. **For 4 File uploads it is triggering pipeline 4 times**

[image]

[image]

Possibly, the way the file is written to storage causes this in your situation. After the file is created with a size of 0, it is updated with its real size. If you choose to disregard the size zero updates.

[image]

Please choose yes for the "Ignore empty blobs" function. The user may regulate how files are uploaded to blogs; ADF does not have any restrictions over this.